# Select a discontiguous range

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm building an office-js add-in for Excel. I need to select two non-adjacent cells (e.g A1 and C3).  The following code works to select the multi-cell range starting at A1 and ending at C3.

```
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem('sheet1');
        var range = sheet.getRange('a1:c3');
        range.select();
        return ctx.sync(); 
    });
```

However, I'm looking to select only the two cells (A1 and C3).  In VBA the syntax is

```
worksheets("sheet1").range("a1,c3").select
```

But I cannot find anything analogous in office-js.  I've tried as similar syntax with office-js:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem('sheet1');
        var range = sheet.getRange('a1,c3');
        range.select();
        return ctx.sync(); 
});
```

but it fails with: {"code":"InvalidArgument","message":"The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.","errorLocation":"Worksheet.getRange"}

Comment: the API is available in preview today on the latest insiders fast check my answer below. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually on the latest insiders fast (16.0.9327.2006 ) deployed just a few days ago you can actually try our implementation for Areas (aka discontinuous ranges. )

please make sure to use our preview cdn to test this.(https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js)

but basically you can do things like:

```js
function run() {
    return Excel.run(function (context) {
        var range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
        range.load("address");
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                console.log("The range address was \"" + range.address + "\".");
            });
    });
}
```

and you will see that if you select a non-continuous range you will get something like:  "Sheet1!C6:C14,Sheet1!F12:H22".

you can pass a similar string on the getRange method to create an Area and simultaneously format it etc.

Please give it a try and send us your feedback!  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An API to work with discontinuous ranges is not yet available in Office.js. We are working on it and are finalizing the design right now. In the meantime, you will have to create separate range objects for the two cells and operate on each of them with duplicate commands.

Comment: Suppose I want to create chart from two columns of a table, and the columns are not adjacent (like column A and D). In this case how do we give two ranges to the `worksheet.charts.add()` method as it only accepts one range?

Comment: @Anant_Kumar What you'll have to do is create a new 2-column range on a hidden worksheet. Copy the data from columns A and D to columns A and B of the new range. Then pass the new range to `worksheet.charts.add`.

Answer (score 1):

```
context.workbook.getSelectedRange()
```

is used for contiguous ranges.

If you want to get the range for a discontiguous range you should use:

```
context.workbook.getSelectedRanges()
```